# My desktop has one VGA port and one HDMI port. Can I use two monitors with only these two ports?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

OS: Vista Home Premium 64 bit with Sp1
Graphics:ATI Radeon HD 3200
Processor:  AMD Phenom X4 9500 Quad Core
RAM:  8 GB DDR2

My wife just got me a second monitor and my tower has only one VGA port and one HDMI port.  Is there an easy way I can implement the second monitor?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Just plug it in. Most likely it'll work. If it doesn't just get a PCI-E display card that gives you two display output and a boost to the 3D capability as HD 3200 is getting old. If you don't want to open the case get a USB to VGA/DVI adapter. They are on the cheap nowadays